# How to Form URL to Fetch Items From a Sharepoint List via Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am having difficulty forming the url for the call. Examples in tutorial are given in a different way than the url I have.

the url I want to call;
https://blahblah.sharepoint.com/teams/projectname/Lists/listname/AllItems.aspx?skipSignal=true

the url structure on the tutorial;

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}?expand=columns,items(expand=fields)

List list = graphClient.sites("{site-id}").lists("{list-id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first URL (with `AllItems.aspx`) is the URL to display the list in your web browser (with the interface, logo, navigation, etc.). To get only data in JSON, you can use `Graph API` (but also `REST API`). The documentation for Graph API is correct.

So, the URL for **Graph API** should be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/YOUR-SITE-GUID/lists/YOUR-LIST-GUID/items?expand=fields
```

You can get the GUID of your site with this URL:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/site/id
```

For the list GUID, similarly, you get it with this URL:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists
```

It's probably easier to get data with [**REST API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieving-lists-and-list-properties-with-rest), and not Graph API, with this URL. You can test it directly in your web browser:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('YOUR-LIST-TITLE')/items
```